# Ionic dynamic image working on iOS 11.2 on iPhone 8, 7 yet not on 11.2 on iPhone 6

Tags: firebase, ionic3

I'm trying to dynamically load an image in a menu from firebase on an ionic 3 project.

The database loads a config node with a banner image url.

I've tried assigning the url to the image like :

```
(<HTMLImageElement>document.querySelector("img[name='menubanner']")).src = this.bannerimage;
```

This works great on iPhone 7 and 8 models.

Also trying seting a this.variable and calling it like:

```
 <a href="{{bannerurl}}"><img src="{{bannerimage}}" /></a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Its a tight deadline :/
Thanks
Kieran

Answer (score 1):

In your code where you set `bannerImage`, you could try:

```
this.bannerimage = normalizeURL(this.bannerimage);
```

Refer this [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/#rewriting-file).

Comment: Gave that a try. Still nothing showing up. Is it because its a side menu?

Comment: I'm not sure then. The strange thing is that it works on the same OS, just not a different phone model.

Comment: Its really odd. I'm thinking it is a screensize and css issue. I've implemented an Ion-card with an image instead. Seems to be working. Had CSS to keep the image at the bottom of the page too. So perhaps it was some strange bug due to styling? - Oh and the card with no positioning is working. Hard to delete the app from the emulator too